# android relativelayout xml background image with many relative textviews (dynamic clock)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to make something like an analog clock with a background image and many `TextView`s.

The `TextView`s will get the data programmatically, which is working. But my problem is the design. How can I set the `TextView`'s position in relation to the background image? It should work on different screen sizes ...

Is there maybe a way to take the middle of the screen and set a margin to the center for each of them, like I foretold with the arrow in the picture?

[image: http://i43.tinypic.com/2w2ebr5.jpg]